# Changing the first letter after ] to uppercase

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have a CSV file in which I have thousands of lines like this:

```
bla bla blab [FR] john is bla bla
bla [US] blue house in Chicago...
[ES] accessing the safe... bla bla
```

See the elements between `[ ]`? These elements are always followed by a space and the start of a new phrase. I want to convert the first letter found after the space to uppercase, making the file like

```
bla bla blab [FR] John is bla bla
bla [US] Blue house in Chicago...
[ES] Accessing the safe... bla bla
```

How do I do that from terminal, using, sed, awk or whatever?

Please explain the solution, I want to understand and learn.

Thanks.

Comment: Can the `[..]` be the last word in a line? If so, should the word in next line be handled?

Comment: no. `[..]` is never the last thing in a line. There is always a space and a phrase starting after that.

Comment: The title asks for the first letter after a character. So what about `[US] 12 people were found...`? Should `p` become uppercase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If on a GNU system, you can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/] ./\U&/g' <infile
```

**s**tream **ed**itor '**s**ubstitute/*replace-what*/*replace-with*/**g**lobally' <inputfile

Here "*replace-what*" is a literal `]` followed by a single space   then a single character (`.` matches a single character except `\n`ewline but would match a `\n`ewline character if it was ever found in the pattern space. In `perl`, it doesn't unless the `s` flag is added to the regex.)

"*replace-what*" is `\U&`, in sed `&` is back-reference to "replace-what" part (`\U` stands for `\Upper-case`), so `\U&` will replace matched part to Upper-case.

---

If your `sed` is not GNU `sed`, you could do the same with `perl` with:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/] ./\U$&/g' < infile
```

Comment: Not working for me. It is converting things like `[FR]` into `[FRU]` and removing what is inside the brackets for other cases.

Comment: yep, macOS. `sed --version` = `illegal option` on macOS. I am on Catalina.

Comment: ahhhhhh, the perl version works wonderfully. Thanks.

Comment: In `sed`, `.` would match a newline character if it was ever found in the pattern space. In perl, it doesn't unless the `s` flag is added to the regex.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for perl command and correction as well as explanation on `.` match in sed. I have added into body of answer, thanks

Answer (score 6):

POSIXly, you could do:

```
awk -F '] ' '{
  out = $1
  for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
    out = out FS toupper(substr($i, 1, 1)) substr($i, 2)
  print out}' < infile
```

Or:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {FS = OFS = "] "}
  {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
      $i = toupper(substr($i, 1, 1)) substr($i, 2)
    print
  }' < infile
```

That defines `"] "` as the `F`ield `S`eparator, and we join the fields back together after having converted the first character of each field (starting from the `2`nd and up to `NF` the `N`umber of `F`ields) `to` `upper`case.

(beware however that a few `awk` implementations including `mawk` and FreeBSD `awk` (so possibly macOS' as well) have not been internationalised, so would fail to change `[GR] π` into `[GR] Π` (or `[FR] éric` into `[FR] Éric` if `é` was expressed in its pre-composed form (U+00E9)).

Answer (score 1):

First, you can set FS: `-v FS="[]][[:space:]]+"` i.e. `[]]` followed by `[[:space:]]+`. With this you can get the field for making changes:

```
$ awk -v FS="[]][[:space:]]+" '{print  $2}' file
john is bla bla
blue house in Chicago...
accessing the safe... bla bla
```

Here you "want to convert the first letter found after the space to uppercase", so you can test:

```
awk -v FS="[]][[:space:]]+" '{print toupper(substr($2,1,1))substr($2,2)}'  file

John is bla bla
Blue house in Chicago...
Accessing the safe... bla bla
```

and print all:

```
$ awk -v FS="[]][[:space:]]+" '{print $1, toupper(substr($2,1,1))substr($2,2)}'  file
bla bla blab [FR John is bla bla
bla [US Blue house in Chicago...
[ES Accessing the safe... bla bla
```

but you see a problem: the separator's chars are missing. In these cases we can use the 4th argument of the `split()` function and insert `FS` in the function. So with this you can get changes and the desired output:

```
awk -v FS="[]][[:space:]]+" '                                              
{
split($0, a, FS, seps)
a[i]=$1
a[2]= toupper(substr($2,1,1))substr($2,2)
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
printf "%s%s", a[i], seps[i]
print ""
  }
' file
bla bla blab [FR] John is bla bla
bla [US] Blue house in Chicago...
[ES] Accessing the safe... bla bla
```

Thanks to Ed Morton code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22211988 Here you can see details.